# UI5: refresh Table containing relative timestamp without changes in the Model

Tags: sapui5

**The Problem**

I am currently working on a View containing a Table. One of the columns is a relative time stamp of the last update of the elements in the table (Last Update: 6 seconds ago), using

```
<Text text="{
  path: 'lastUpdate',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime',
  formatOptions: {
    source: {pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ'}, 
    relative: true,
    relativeScale: 'auto'
  }
}"/>
```

Until now I have transmitted the current model from the backend with every get request, so the view always updated itself with the model on every update. However, to save bandwidth I have decided to place in a `If-Modified-Since` condition into the call, so that the backend will only send me the model if it actually has been updated since the last call, otherwise it returns a 304.

The issue I'm having now, however, is that since the model doesn't get replaced anymore, the view is equally not updated and the most recent event will be stuck on e.g. "Last Update: 15 seconds ago" for potentially minutes; until a new update comes in.

**Question**

I'm looking for a function that tells the view (or even just the table or the particular column) to refresh its content according to the new current time, even if the underlying data has not changed.

So far, I found and tried

`that.byId("myTable").getBinding("items").refresh();`

but that didn't do anything, I assume because it still recognized that the data hadn't changed.

Edit: Going by the accepted answer, calling `that.getView().getModel().refresh(true);` did yield the intended results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use `.refresh(true)`

The DemoKit show for the sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding:

```
refresh(bForceUpdate?, sGroupId?) : void
```

with bForceUpdate meaning "Update the bound control even if no data has been changed"

Comment: I did try it on refreshing the table binding without success, but calling ```.refresh(true);``` on the Model of the view instead of the table did work as intended.